# CSS drop down Menu alignment

Tags: html, css

I Have The CSS in Drop Down menu

```
#templatemo_menu {
display: block;
width: 910px;
height: 60px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background: #4c4032 url(images/templatemo_menu_background.gif) no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_menu li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
position:relative;
}

#templatemo_menu ul {
padding: 15px 0 0 0;
margin: 0 0 0 120px;
list-style: none;
}
#templatemo_menu ul li a{   
padding: 0 30px;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
color: #FFFFFF;
display:block;

}

#templatemo_menu ul ul{

position:absolute;
left:0px;
display:none;

}
```

controls children boxes in navigation bar when hovered on parent box

```
#templatemo_menu ul li:hover ul{
color: #fe551e;
display:block;

}

#templatemo_menu li a:hover, #templatemo_menu li .current{
color: #fe551e;
}
```

My Problem is : not align with the parent

Check The Link =  http://charity.teleoutsourcing.com/Charities/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin from `#templatemo_menu ul ul`

this will solve your issue.

Comment: I remove the left:0px; but its still the same , not aligned

Comment: can you please update your css here  http://charity.teleoutsourcing.com/Charities/index.php

Comment: I Update it already try to look the "Others" tab besides Achievement thats my problem

Comment: add margin-left:0 in { #templatemo_menu ul ul }, its not showing

Comment: Its Working Now ,,Thank You

Comment: How can I Change in one lane the "About us" in Others Tab?

Comment: you need to add some style for that

Comment: I have mention some style here, adjust the style as per your need http://jsfiddle.net/9heLnopj/